# Attaching jQuery event to more than one selector in one call

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've basically written a script that will animate the window to a selected element however I found myself writing this 5 times for each link.

e.g:
   This is the HTML (just a standard nav)

```
<nav>
  <a class="nav_link1"></a>
  <a class="nav_link2"></a>
  <a class="nav_link3"></a>
</nav>




$('.nav_link1').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#section_link1').offset().top}, 300);
})
$('.nav_link2').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#section_link2').offset().top}, 300);
})
$('.nav_link3').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#section_link3').offset().top}, 300);
})
```

I was wondering how I could use a defined array (each) to consolidate this into one block.

Can this be done?

```
var linkitem = ['link1','link2','link3']
$('.nav_linkitem').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#section_linkitem').offset().top}, 300);
})
```

Comment: Can you show us how link1, 2 and 3 look like in terms of HTML? it may help finding a shorter way to write the query

Comment: It's just a standard nav with a tags.  I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try using comma delimited selectors and the "this" keyword.

```
$("body").on("click", "#section_link1,#section_link2,#section_link3", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 300);
});
```

Or create a common css class for all of them and just use $(".myLinkClass") to find them all in one shot.

```
$("body").on("click", ".myLinkClass", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native javascript's `for` loop like this:

```
var linkitems = ['link1','link2','link3']

for (i = 0; i < linkitems.length; i++) {
    $('.nav_'+linkitems[i]).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#section_'+linkitems[i]).offset().top}, 300);
    })
}
```

Comment: I think this maybe what I'm looking for however I would need to add implement the array into the selector too. would it be $('.nav_'+linkitems[i]).click....etc?

Comment: Yup, I edited the answer. Keep in mind that whatever you put inside the `$()` is essentially a string. So you can append whatever you like to that like I did above. So you can replace `$('.nav_linkitem').click()` by `selector = '.nav_linkitem'; $(selector).click()`